# Cant toggle visibility of blockquotes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here I am learning basic Jquery functions. I am trying to make the active blockquote to become visible while the others stay closed or close. Toggling so to speak. Only one at a time.

```
$('.read').click(function() {
    $("blockquote.visible").removeClass("visible")
    $("blockquote").addClass("visible")
    });
```

I made an example in Jsiddle and nearly got it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/w3jdm8am/10/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
$('.read').click(function() {
  $("blockquote").removeClass("visible")
  $(this).parents('.container').next("blockquote").addClass("visible")
});
```

```css
blockquote {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s all
}
.visible {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="news">
  <h2><span>Quotes</span></h2>
  <div class="info">Some cool quotes</div>

  <article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <aside>
        <p>Beethovens best quote!</p>
        <div class="read">Read</div>
      </aside>
    </div>

    <blockquote>
      Some text
    </blockquote>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <aside>
        <p>Mozarts best quote!</p>
        <div class="read">Read</div>
      </aside>
    </div>

    <blockquote>
      Some Text
    </blockquote>

  </article>
</div>
```

Another way to do it

```js
$('.read').click(function() {
  var ele=$(this).parents('.container').next("blockquote");
  $("blockquote").not(ele).removeClass("visible");
  ele.toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
blockquote {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s all
}
.visible {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="news">
  <h2><span>Quotes</span></h2>
  <div class="info">Some cool quotes</div>

  <article>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <aside>
        <p>Beethovens best quote!</p>
        <div class="read">Read</div>
      </aside>
    </div>

    <blockquote>
      Some text
    </blockquote>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="image"></div>
      <aside>
        <p>Mozarts best quote!</p>
        <div class="read">Read</div>
      </aside>
    </div>

    <blockquote>
      Some Text
    </blockquote>

  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `.parent()` twice, you also can use `.parents('.container')`

Comment: also `closest()` is possible here